# Batch file to create a 'file shortcut' and move the created shortcut to a set destination

Tags: batch, shortcuts

I have been playing with the batch files above and have created a batch file based on it. The changes in my file are extracting the 'Full path & Filename' %~f1.lnk so that the batch file will be called from any folder as the file itself would be within the %path% variable.

It works fine and I can call it using a right click menu option. However it makes the 'shortcut' in the same location as the original file. The problem I have is I cannot work out how to send the actual 'shortcut file' to the Sendto folder where it will be available to any file I right click on. I'm clearly missing a very obvious solution.

Can anyone help or give a pointer to the solution.

```
@echo off
echo Set oWS = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") > CreateShortcut.vbs
echo sLinkFile = "%~f1.lnk" >> CreateShortcut.vbs
echo Set oLink = oWS.CreateShortcut(sLinkFile) >> CreateShortcut.vbs
echo oLink.TargetPath = "%~f1" >> CreateShortcut.vbs
echo oLink.Save >> CreateShortcut.vbs
cscript CreateShortcut.vbs
CreateShortcut.vbs
```

Thanks for any assistance anyone may be able to provide.